# Celery worker not running: Not able to register the task

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

The celery worker is giving me error saying unregistered task. I am using celeryd as daemon. Restarting didn't help.

Here is my task.py
celeryApp > tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import task

@task
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
```

celeryProj.py << I have changed the name from celery.py as it was creating problem

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# Indicate Celery to use the default Django settings module
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_proj.settings')

app = Celery('my_app')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
# This line will tell Celery to autodiscover all your tasks.py that are in your app     folders
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

__init__.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celeryProj import app as celeryApp
```

settings.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import sys
import djcelery
from celery.schedules import crontab


djcelery.setup_loader()

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ..
    ...
    'my_app',
    'djcelery',
    'celeryApp',
)

BROKER_URL = "amqp://user:password@localhost:5672/v_host"

## celery configrations 

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'

## These config can be commented in production

CELERY_BIN = "/usr/local/bin/celery"
CELERYD_NODES = "worker1 worker2 worker3"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/user/proj/"
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1


CELERY_IMPORTS = ('celeryApp.tasks',)
```

My directory structure is :

```
myProj > my_app ,\_\_init\_\_.py, setting.py, celeryProj.py
myProj > celeryApp > tasks.py
```

I am getting this error log:

```
[2014-07-06 10:17:43,674: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type u'celeryApp.tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{u'utc': True, u'chord': None, u'args': [2, 2], u'retries': 0, u'expires': None, u'task': u'celeryApp.tasks.add', u'callbacks': None, u'errbacks': None, u'timelimit': [None, None], u'taskset': None, u'kwargs': {}, u'eta': None, u'id': u'620007e6-4c7d-49cc-9516-4f089c200df9'} (260b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 455, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: u'celeryApp.tasks.add'
```

Comment: In `tasks.py`, try using `from celeryProj import app` and `@app.task` instead of `@task`.

Comment: Didnt help. This is working fine when I use it in foreground with runserver. Now I used supervisor as workaround